# Memory Access for class instances

Tags: swift, class, memory, memory-management, memory-access

Consider the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 
    var dummy = DummyClass()
 
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var copyDummy = dummy
        
        if (copyDummy === dummy){
            print("Same instance")
        }
        increment(&copyDummy)
       
    }
    
    func increment(_ number: inout DummyClass) {
        number.change += dummy.change

    }
}


class DummyClass {
    var change = 10
}
```

Now from my understanding, both copyDummy and dummy point to the same memory location.

When I call `func increment` using `increment(&dummy)` there is a runtime error since I am trying to write and read the same memory location simultaneously.

But when I call`increment(&copyDummy)` there is no error.

Why such behaviour if copyDummy is also accessing the same memory location as dummy variable?

Sorry if this turns to be a very basic question and/or if I have got my understanding incorrect. I am trying to wrap my head around this from quite some time.

Thanks in advance!

**Modified code** as per helpful suggestions:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 
    var dummy = DummyClass()
 
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        increment(dummy)
    }
    
    func increment(_ number: DummyClass) {
        number.change += dummy.change
    }
}


class DummyClass {
    var change = 10
}
```

Isnt func increment writing the same memory location ie. `numbers.change` from where its also reading ie. `dummy.change`

Comment: `increment` works with reference to reference. I can't understand why would this be needed as you can just remove `inout` and work with reference, and it will work for both cases.

Comment: Hi Asperi! Thanks for the comment. The question is to understand how memory access works for class instances and the func created is just to demonstrate my confusion wrt the same. When you say increment works with ref to ref, could you please elaborate on the same?

Comment: Class is a reference type, ie when you create `dummy` it is already a reference to some memory where real created object data is located, so why you pass `&dummy` you create a reference to reference to memory.

Comment: Thanks Asperi! Followup question - If I remove the inout declaration, like so `func increment(_ number: DummyClass) { number.change += dummy.change}` and try to call the func `increment(dummy)`, in regards to memory access - Am i not writing `numbers.change` to the same memory location from where I am reading `dummy.change`?